# How do I get hamcrest-all into an Eclipse Xtext plugin project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext, hamcrest

I've been pulling my hair out for the better part of my weekend trying to get `hacrest-all:1.3.0` or `hamcrest:2.2.0` (prefered) into my freshly generated Xtext 21.1 plugin project.

As far as I can tell, the issue has to do with xtext.testing package depending on `hamcrest.core:1.3.0`, which is the only package in the orbit p2 repos. No problem, I will just add the jars manually, but as soon as I actually call any of the `org.hamcres.Matchers.*`, I get...

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.hamcrest.Matchers"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

Well crap. I have tried just about every way imaginable to get this dependency hooked (ok well four, maven/jars x 1.3.0/2.2.0).

The strange thing is that I was doing this just fine on an [older Xtext project](https://github.com/drkstr101/Natural/tree/next/org.agileware.natural.cucumber.tests).

But when I create a new Xtext project using the Wizard, I can no longer seem to hook up any useful hacrest matchers.

I just copied the same setup from the last project (with the jar file linked in `build.properties`), but nothing I can do in this fresh project seems to work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Full source can be found in [org.agileware.natural.jbehave2.tests](https://github.com/drkstr101/Natural/tree/jbehave2/org.agileware.natural.jbehave2.tests) if it helps at all.

Thanks for your time!

**UPDATE**

I just realized the difference with the old project. It's not using maven!! So we have the source of the problem... is there a way to fix it without ditching maven builds? I would very much like to not be tied to Eclipse IDE for builds, please and thank you!

Comment: are you talking about maven or eclipse/tycho. see https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20200224183213/

Comment: I did see this, and had already added it to my target. Only hamcrest.core is resolvable though: https://github.com/drkstr101/Natural/blob/jbehave2/org.agileware.natural.jbehave2.target/org.agileware.natural.jbehave2.target.target

Comment: Maybe I need to refresh or something after I changed it? It orbit drop is expected solution then I'll play around with it more to see what's up.

Comment: where do you see the hamcrest dependency in Xtext?

Comment: ps. the maven build on your branch works perfectly fine

Comment: It's because I switched back to CoreMatchers.*. Here I will submit a commit right now that breaks testing ... and sent.

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I don't actually know if xtext depends on hamcrest.core. I just assumed that's where it was coming from because it is in my list of dependencies when generating new project. See initital commit.

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I've added a potential workaround as an unaccepted answer as it works in Eclipse, but then breaks Maven builds. I still haven't found any way for it to work in both Eclipse and Maven at the same time (trust me, I've looked haha).

Comment: i still dont understand why adapting the target platform does not work for your

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Well I think I found the cause of the breakdown. I was able to continue using hamcrest-2.2 in my previous project, all the way up until I added an explicit dependency on 'org.junit' to get TestSuite type in my project. I suppose I can live without TestSuite more than I can live without useful Matchers, and there does mot appear to be a hard req on `org.junit` dep in MANIFEST. And perhaps adding org.hamcrest.library before junit will fix... haven't tried yet. Low priority and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to adding it to the `build.properties`, I also had to open the Project Settings and manually add the jar to the `Java Build Path` -> `Libraries`. While not strictly necessary for all jars, this allows one to specify the import order, giving the included jar first priority as expected.

**Update**

Here are the steps I took to get everything running smoothly.

1. Grab hamcrest-2.2.jar and place them somewhere in a bundle.
2. Set `jars.extra.classpath` in the `build.properties` in your test projects like so:

   ```
   jars.extra.classpath = platform:/plugin/org.example.mydsl.testing/lib/hamcrest-2.2.jar
   ```
3. The `MANIFEST.MF` in your test projects should have `Require-Bundle` and `Import-Package` sections similar to this:

```
Require-Bundle: org.example.mydsl,
 org.example.mydsl.testing,
 org.eclipse.xtext.testing,
 org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.testing,
 org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib;bundle-version="2.14.0"
Import-Package: org.apache.commons.logging,
 org.apache.log4j,
 org.junit,
 org.junit.runner,
 org.junit.runner.manipulation,
 org.junit.runner.notification,
 org.junit.runners,
 org.junit.runners.model
```

I may have possibly left out a step, but a fully working solution can be found in [rlogiacco/Natural](https://github.com/rlogiacco/Natural/tree/81f619d6a9162422699fbad912c8a1d7b906b99d)

Comment: Actually, while this does fix the tests in Eclipse, the maven build will then fail as it's unaware of this import order, and removing it from build.properties will result in Matchers not being present on the classpath. Unfortunately, this is still an open question so I will not be marking my answer as accepted.

Comment: you also need to add the jar to manifest instead of java build path

Comment: I did finally get this all working, but it's a bit hacky. I needed to fiddle with the default junit dependencies to get junit the api, but not junit the framework. I will update my answer with the steps I took.